# Ruby local variables in a for loop

Tags: ruby, for-loop, local-variables

I would like to know if it is possible to set local variables in Ruby `for` loop.

More precisely I would like to have the `for` loop to behave like this:

```
tmp = 0
1.upto(5) { |i;tmp| puts i; tmp = i; } ; "tmp: #{tmp}"
```

The `tmp` variable should not be modified by what runs inside the foor loop.

Comment: Right, sorry for misguiding comment.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? If you don't want a variable from outside get changed inside a loop, then don't change it. What is the point of assignment inside loop, if you don't want it to change?

Comment: I would like to use the `for` loop as i do in other programming languages, to keep a common pattern. It would be a substantial benefit to be able to definire local variables in the loop, i don't think i need to argument why it is so.

Comment: When I run your code, the outer `tmp` is indeed not modified. The block-local variable `tmp` masks it. How is this is not what you want?

Comment: @max, I don't understand well your question. The behaviour in the example is what i want. I was asking for a way to achieve that in a for loop.

Comment: @NicolaMingotti sorry, my bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can introduce a new block for masking the outer variable

```
tmp = 0
for i in (1..5) do
  proc do |;tmp|
    puts i
    tmp = i
  end[]
end
```

This is awful. The difference between `for` and `each` is that the iteration variable in a `for` loop *pollutes the outer scope*.

```
x = []
# i has same scope as x
for i in (1..3)
  # closure captures i outside the loop scope, so...
  x << lambda { i }
end
# WAT
x.map(&:call) # [3, 3, 3]

x = []
(1..3).each { |i| x << lambda { i } }
# sanity restored
x.map(&:call) # [1, 2, 3]
```

Using my hack above to make your `for` act more like an `each` makes already confusing behavior even more confusing. Better to avoid `for` entirely.

Comment: Thank you @Max, your example with `proc` answers my question. I agree that it is not a nice structure to see. On the other side, `for` is (with `if`) the most written word in computer programming, it is a pity to leave it out of business in Ruby.

Comment: @NicolaMingotti I haven't written a single `for` loop outside of experiments like this in all my years of using Ruby. I'm pretty sure it's only in there so that people don't freak out when they come over from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that is possible, `for` loops do not have a scope of their own.